# UWP change canvas view based on (x,y)Coordinates of canvas?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a Canvas having width=200000,height=200000.My screensize height and width is 700 and 1400 respectively.If I display the canvas it won't show entire canvas.So i have used pointerWheelChanged event of canvas and I had calculate how much it was scrolled when scrolling the wheel of mouse.i.e.,new (x,y)coordinates of canvas.Still this it worked fine.But i Don't know how to show the canvas from  my new coordinates.

```
Canvas c=new Canvas();
Image img1=new Image();
Image img2=new Image();
c.Children.Add(img1);
c.Children.Add(img2);
Canvas.SetLeft(img1,100);
Canvas.SetTop(img1,200);
Canvas.SetLeft(img2,2000);
Canvas.SetTop(img2,1500);
```

My Canvas has two Images ,one at (100,200) and the other at (2000,1500).If my screen height and width are 700 and 1400 respectively.When I run it ,it shows only the first image in the screen ,because second image was in some other place .i.e.,out of screen(It was hidden).How can I show second image ,based on the data calculate from the mousewheelchanged event.I had calculated it,but i don't know how to show canvas from the calculated value??

In PointerWheelChangedEvent i have added it,

```
Canvas layout = sender as Canvas;
int wheelDelta = e.GetCurrentPoint(layout).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
Boolean isHorizontalSwipe = 
e.GetCurrentPoint(layout).Properties.IsHorizontalMouseWheel;
Point scrollPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(layout).Position;
```

The wheelDelta is added or subracted from current canvas Point based on horizontal or vertical swipe.

what I'm trying to do is?
[image]

Comment: What does "But i Don't know how to show the canvas from my new coordinates." mean? Do you mean you can calculate how much the mouse wheel scroll, but you don't know how to apply it to the canvas? If it is not, can you show more details about your expected behavior? In addition, can you provide some related code what you have implemented?

Comment: yeah...your are right.I had calculate how much mouse wheel scrolled,but i don't know how to apply to canvas??

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT ,I  had provide some code and explanation ...

Comment: OK, can you show the code snippet about how you calculate in the pointerWheelChanged event?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT i have added some event code for calculation

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Do you have other questions?

Comment: yaeh...its working i have some other problem also...I have Four canvas's .First canvas, height and width are (400,400) placed at ((left,0),(top,0)).Second ,third and fourth canvas height and width are (400,400) ,(400,400),(400,400) placed at  ((left,400),(top,0)), ((left,0),(top,400)) and  ((left,400),(top,400)).This four canvas placed in Parent canvas.I have Image  in fourth canvas at((left,50),(top,50)),while pointerwheelChanged event of fourth canvas Occurs,i'm using this translation property to scroll the 4th canvas content.It Work but,the scrolled image was visible over the other canvas.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT ..help me.

Comment: What does "the scrolled image was visible over the other canvas" mean? Can you show more details about this? It worked well in my side.

Comment: you must know ,what i'm trying to do..please  see the .gif I have added.I don't know hoe to achieve this.For example,in MS-Excel , we can apply freeze pane for rows and columns.While freezing if an image is inserted and then if we scroll the sheet , the image will hide or cropped based on scrolling.i dont know how to achieve this in uwp.

Comment: if we apply freeze for rows and columns,the sheet will split int four section.For this i have used four canvas , one in each section.If i place an image in fourth canvas and used translation property to scroll the canvas.it scrolled but ,but the scrolled image was visible over the other canvas also instead of hiding.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT,I have briefly,explained my case.can u suggesst me how to achieve the case in .gif

Comment: If you want to hide the image which in the forth canvas, you need to add the forth canvas to the parent canvas first, and then add the second ,third and fourth canvas. In this case, the forth canvas is at the bottom, when you scroll the forth canvas, the image in it will be masked by other canvases.

Comment: i have added it first itself...but it does not work

Comment: When I added the forth canvas to the parent canvas first and scroll it, the image will be masked by other canvases. How did you add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a new Translation to Canvas to update position of the Canvas based on the wheelDelta. For example:

```
private void Canvas_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas layout = sender as Canvas;
    int wheelDelta = e.GetCurrentPoint(layout).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
    Boolean isHorizontalSwipe =
    e.GetCurrentPoint(layout).Properties.IsHorizontalMouseWheel;

    if (horizontal swipe) 
    {
        layout.Translation = new Vector3(layout.Translation.X + wheelDelta, layout.Translation.Y, layout.Translation.Z);
    }
    else
    {
        layout.Translation = new Vector3(layout.Translation.X, layout.Translation.Y + wheelDelta, layout.Translation.Z);
    }
}
```